# Extracting files with specific extensions from a lot of ZIP archives using Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python and cant seem to get this thing to work.
The below code is capable of finding ZIP files and extracting exactly what i 
want as long as there is only one ZIP file in a folder. The problem seems to raise as zipfile.ZipFile reads returned values from the first function as one big string and not as paths and i run out of ides how to fix this one.

```
import zipfile
import os
import fnmatch


def archive1():
    myarchive = []
    rootPath= (r'E:\Test\2017')
    pattern = '*.zip'
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
         for filename in fnmatch.filter(files,pattern):
            zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(root, filename))
            myarchive.append(os.path.join(root,filename))
    return str(myarchive).replace('[',"").replace(']',"").replace('"',"").replace("'","")
    #this is here so function returns as string and replace characters so second function reads it as applicable path(s).             

if __name__ == '__main__':
    archive1()

myarchive1 = archive1()

def extractor():
    new_dr = r'E:\Test'
    extensions = ('.txt','.pdf')
    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(myarchive1)
    print (zip_file)
    [zip_file.extract(file,new_dr) for file in zip_file.namelist() if file.endswith(extensions)]
    zip_file.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    extractor()
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\VSC_Folder\totalni_test.py", line 30, in <module>
    extractor()
  File "e:\VSC_Folder\totalni_test.py", line 24, in extractor
    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(myarchive1)
  File "C:\Users\Thiothixene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\zipfile.py", line 1090, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
 OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'E:\\\\Test\\\\2017\\\\test2.zip, 
   E:\\\\Test\\\\2017\\\\ZG.zip'
```

Comment: just pass the zipfile object to the extractor as param. You shouldn't try to parse the filepath out of string representation of the list - this is a no no.

Comment: Yeah. It seems that was answer. I am new so i  know i have a lot to learn yet. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply pass the zipfile object to the extractor as param. You shouldn't try to parse the filepath out of string representation of the list - that is most likely what causes problem. Try something like:

```
import zipfile
import os
import fnmatch

def archive1():
    rootPath= (r'E:\Test\2017')
    pattern = '*.zip'
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
         for filename in fnmatch.filter(files,pattern):
            with zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(root, filename)) as zf:
                extractor(zf)

def extractor(zip_file):
    new_dr = r'E:\Test'
    extensions = ('.txt','.pdf')
    [zip_file.extract(file,new_dr) for file in zip_file.namelist() if file.endswith(extensions)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    archive1()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess i have a lot to learn :) This worked like charm. The only thing i had to do is change  '(' after 'with' statement. Thank you again.

Comment: Great to hear that as I didn't really test it myself :)